# How can I show flatness of this morphism using local algebra?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, localization, flatness, local-rings

Consider the obviously non-flat morphism of schemes
$$
\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)) \to \text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x])
$$
How can I show that it is not flat using local algebra? I've looked at a few local algebra morphisms
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)} \to (\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy))_{(x)} \\
\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)} \to (\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy))_{(x,y)} \\
\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)} \to (\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy))_{(x,y-1)}
\end{align}
$$
and tried to come up with an exact sequence where they do not preserve injectivity, but haven't been able to find one. Do you have any hints?

---

It seems like parts 2 and 4 of proposition 5 in https://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/Math%20_256B--09/Supplements/flat.pdf should help, but I'm not convinced that the tensor of the residue field is zero for any of the previous modules.

---

As per Mohan's suggestion, we can take the sequence
$$
0 \to \mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)} \xrightarrow{\cdot x} \mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)}
$$
and tensor it with our local algebra. Since $xy = 0$ in the module we have that
$$
(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy))_{(x)} \xrightarrow{\cdot x}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy))_{(x)}
$$
is not injective.

Comment: If $A\to B$ is flat and $x$ is non-zero divisor in $A$, then $x$ is a non-zero divisor in in $B$.

Comment: @Mohan Okay, so then $0 \to A \xrightarrow{\cdot x} A$ is not preserved under tensor product. Thanks!

Comment: @Mohan So then I wonder why $A\otimes \mathbb{C} = 0$...